# Snowflake JDBC batch insert fails with "Bind variable ? not set" when specifying type in the query using "?::TIMESTAMP_NTZ"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using JDBC driver to connect to Snowflake and perform inserts. 
Table can have multiple timestamp column, that means single insert query might have to deal with both timestamp_ntz and timestamp_ltz.

It works fine, when we specify the type in the query while binding values as below

```
INSERT INTO <TABLENAME> VALUES(?::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, ?::TIMETAMP_LTZ)
```

However, when we try the same with addBatch() and executeBatch(), it fails with "Bind variable ? not set"

Sample program -

```
try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
    con.createStatement().execute("create or replace table Test_TSNTZ(t1 TIMESTAMPNTZ)");
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Test_TSNTZ values (? ::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)"))  {
        java.sql.Timestamp t = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2019-09-23 10:10:10.0");
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
            ps.setTimestamp(1, t);
            ps.addBatch();
        }
        ps.executeBatch();

        try (Statement statement = con.createStatement()) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from Test_TSNTZ ")) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getTimestamp(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the type of the table is `TIMESTAMPNTZ` is that a typo? is seems like it should be 'TIMESTAMP_NTZ' .

Comment: it also seems really strange the way you have frame the question, "having both types of timestamp" if you are storing NTZ and LTZ, how are you knowing in the server which is which? we often store everything in UTC in the DB, so there is no jumps gaps or confusion when working, just just have understand how (what TZ) you want to present in the UI. so it seems mixed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, the JDBC connector (*not sure if it's specific to Snowflake*) is not able to bind the variables in a **batch**, if the variable is surrounded in a function or casting operator.

As a workaround, you can send the timestamp values as string. Snowflake will convert it to the column type:

```
try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
    con.createStatement().execute("create or replace table Test_TSNTZ(t1 TIMESTAMP_NTZ, t2 TIMESTAMP_LTZ)");
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Test_TSNTZ values ( ?, ? )"))  {
        java.sql.Timestamp t = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2019-09-23 10:10:10.0");
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
            ps.setString(1, t.toString());
            ps.setString(2, t.toString());
            ps.addBatch();
        }
        ps.executeBatch();

        try (Statement statement = con.createStatement()) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from Test_TSNTZ ")) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getTimestamp(1) + "," + resultSet.getTimestamp(2) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gokhan Atil for sharing workaround. Is there any specific care need to be taken here? I mean do we need to convert the timestamp in any specific format or time zone and later use with setString? It does look like a defect, if not then looking for a way to solve this usecase.

Comment: On my tests, it did not require to enter a specific format. Java timestamp uses a compatible format with Snowflake. Snowflake will attempt to automatically detect the format of timestamps in anyway.